# Include a Russian version for the post notices

Tags: feature-request

Considering the last wave, we've had a ton of new users which have been providing answers to our questions and this is good. But some of these answers were too short or lacked something else, so I added post notices or directly commented. Additionally, these answers were in Russian only.

That makes me suppose they are not that good with English.

Therefore I've been thinking of doing some changes to the post notices. Post notices are those yellow things you see under posts that let the author know that there is something wrong with the post. If you want to propose a translation, this is the text of the post notices. If someone already provided a good translation, please try to work on that.

**Proposal**:  The best idea would be to include 3 additional choices which basically provide the same post notices, simply translated in Russian.

> **citation needed**
> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
>
> **current event**
> Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
>
> **insufficient explanation**
> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective (this is a link, ignore this)] for more information.

Comment: I do not understand: do you want to replace English notices with those in Russian, or make it possible to choose between two languages when posting a notice?

Comment: @texnic The second. The Russian is for when I need to notify some new user who is poor with English. For the rest of us, English is still needed.

Answer (score 3):

I just confirmed to myself, again, that understanding a statement in one language and writing an explanation in another are two very different things. Here's the draft translation of the notices.  There are some places that don't sound quite right, but I couldn't come up with anything better.  By all means, please correct as required.

> **необходима ссылка**
>   В этом сообщении не указаны источники информации. Пожалуйста, помогите улучшить объяснение, добавив ссылки на достоверные источники.  Материал без таких ссылок может быть оспорен и удалён.
>
> **текущее событие**
>   Это сообщение связано с быстро изменяющимся событием.
>
> **недостаточное объяснение**
>   Мы предпочитаем подробные ответы, в которых содержатся объяснение и контекст. Пожалуйста, не давайте ответ в одну строчку: объясните, почему вы рекомендуете его как решение.  Ответы, не содержащие объяснений, будут удалены.  Дополнительную информацию можно найти в разделе [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective(this is a link)] (Хорошо/Плохо высказанная точка зрения).

Comment: Thank you Aleks! :D I'll wait for some native speaker to review it, as more eyes are better than two. :P

Comment: @Alenanno Sure. I am a native speaker, so quite confident in the translation.  Yet I agree that two sets of eyes are better than one.

Comment: I wasn't sure you were a native speaker but I figured so. :)

Comment: Corrected two typos, one comma and a little on style :) Otherwise a nice translation.

Comment: @texnic Thanks.

Comment: I corrected one more mistake, now I believe that it's correct.